# Attach animated gif to email

Tags: email, gif

Is there anyway I can attach an `animated GIF` to email so that it plays?
Right now it only shows 1 frame.

Thank you

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: I sure hope not...  The potential for abuse ans misuse far outweighs the value you might get in a very few appropriate situations.

Comment: plays where? this is dependent on the client

Answer (score 2):

Send it as an attachment,
or embed it as a link.

Depending upon your (and their) email client, it may or may not appear animated on the recipient's end, but at least the image will be sent to the recipient(s).